# Automatically simplifying/refactoring Python code (e.g. for loops -> list comprehension)?

Tags: python, refactoring, list-comprehension, simplify, automated-refactoring

In Python, I really enjoy how concise an implementation can be when using list comprehension. I love to do concise list comprehensions this:

```
myList = [1, 5, 11, 20, 30, 35] #input data
bigNumbers = [x for x in myList if x > 10]
```

However, I often encounter more verbose implementations like this:

```
myList = [1, 5, 11, 20, 30, 35] #input data
bigNumbers = []
for i in xrange(0, len(myList)):
    if myList[i] > 10:
        bigNumbers.append(myList[i])
```

When a `for loop` only looks through one data structure (e.g. `myList[]`), there is usually a straightforward list comprehension statement that is equivalent to the loop. 
**With this in mind, is there a refactoring tool that converts verbose Python loops into concise list comprehension statements?**

---

[Previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532525/how-do-i-make-this-simple-list-comprehension?rq=1) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637037/replacing-while-loop-with-list-comprehension) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532525/how-do-i-make-this-simple-list-comprehension?rq=1) have asked for advice on transforming loops into list comprehension. But, I have yet to find a question about **automatically** converting loops into list comprehension expressions.

---

**Motivation:** There are numerous ways to answer the question "what does it mean for code to be clean?" Personally, I find that making code concise and getting rid of some of the fluff tends to make code cleaner and more readable. Naturally there's a line in the sand between "concise code" and "incomprehensible one-liners." Still, I often find it satisfying to write and work with concise code.

Comment: That's what I would do too. Unfortunately, I see a lot of unnecessarily verbose code like this. Are there refactoring tools that would replace `xrange(0, len(myList))` with `enumerate(myList)`? This would be especially useful when trying to clean up someone else's code, or trying to convert some messy code into something that's usable in a tutorial.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, or just use `for elem in myList:`.

Comment: `What is Pythonic?

"for i in range(len(seq)):"? No.

Use "for obj in seq:".`

Comment: @solvingPuzzles I did some googling but can't seem to find anything that modifies the source in a way that while loops are changed into for-loop or LC. Everything was related to profiling and static code analysis.

Comment: I love writing concise code too, but I also want to keep it readable. It's not hard to convert a loop into a list comprehension by hand, I wouldn't trust a tool to do it.

Comment: One way of doing that _automatically_ would be to use `urllib` to post a question on SO, wait 2-3 minutes and then download the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) is a refactoring tool that can perform arbitrary refactorings, as long as you can specify them with a syntactical pattern. The pattern you might want to look for is this

```
VARIABLE1 = []
for VARIABLE2 in EXPRESSION1:
    if EXPRESSION2:
        VARIABLE1.append(EXPRESSION3)
```

This can be refactored safely to

```
VARIABLE1 = [EXPRESSION3 for VARIABLE2 in EXPRESSION1 if EXPRESSION2]
```

In your specific example, this would give

```
bigNumbers = [myList[i] for i in xrange(0, len(myList)) if myList[i] > 10]
```

Then, you can have another refactoring that replaces xrange(0, N) with xrange(N),
and another one that replaces

```
[VARIABLE1[VARIABLE2] for VARIABLE2 in xrange(len(VARIABLE1)) if EXPRESSION1]
```

with

```
[VARIABLE3 for VARIABLE3 in VARIABLE1 if EXPRESSION1PRIME]
```

There are several problems with this refactoring:

- `EXPRESSION1PRIME` must be `EXPRESSION1` with all occurrences of 
  `VARIABLE1[VARIABLE2]` replaced by VARIABLE3. This is possible with
  2to3, but requires explicit code to do the traversal and replacement.
- `EXPRESSION1PRIME` then must not contain no further occurrences of
  `VARIABLE1`. This can also be checked with explicit code.
- One needs to come up with a name for VARIABLE3. You have chosen `x`;
  there is no reasonable way to have this done automatically. You could
  chose to recycle `VARIABLE1` (i.e. `i`) for that, but that may be confusing
  as it suggests that `i` is still an index. It might work to pick a synthetic
  name, such as `VARIABLE1_VARIABLE2` (i.e. `myList_i`), and check whether
  that's not used otherwise.
- One needs to be sure that VARIABLE1[VARIABLE2] yields the same as you get
  when using `iter(VARIABLE1)`. It's not possible to do this automatically.

If you want to learn how to write 2to3 fixers, take a look at [Lennart Regebro's](http://python3porting.com/fixers.html) book.

Comment: whoa dude what's up with the all caps? that's a bit crazy looking lol

Comment: I was hoping that the caps use is self-evident: they are placeholders, and the rest is concrete syntax.